# Friends (The One with the Jam)

Tags: phrase-meaning

Monica:
I figured out I need to charge seventeen bucks a jar just to break even. So, I've got a new plan now... Babies.

Chandler:
Well, you're gonna need much bigger jars.

What does bigger jars mean?

Comment: Babies don't fit into normal sized jamjars.

Answer (score 1):

Providing more context is, of course, always helpful. [Here is some:](http://friends.tktv.net/Episodes3/summaries/3.html)

> **MONICA:** Joey, take your time with that. That's my last batch.
> **JOEY:** No more jam?!
> **RACHEL:** Well, what happened to your jam plan?
> **MONICA:** I figured out I need to charge seventeen bucks a jar just to break even. So, I've got a new plan now. Babies.
> **CHANDLER:** Well, you're gonna need much bigger jars.
> **ROSS:** What are you talking about?
> **MONICA:** I'm talking about me having a baby.
> **ROSS:** What?
> **RACHEL:** Are you serious?
> **MONICA:** Yeah. The great thing about the jam plan was, I was taking control of my life. So I asked myself, what is the most important thing to me in the world and that's when I came up with the baby plan.

Monica is talking about her "jam plan" and saying her expenses will be too high—she will have to charge way too much money per jar, so no one will buy her jam.
So she is moving on to a different plan, namely, having a baby instead.
As she explains, the "jam plan" wasn't really about making money but about having control over her own life.
The "baby plan" is another way of exerting that control.

But before she explains that, it *sounds like* she means that instead of putting jam in jars and selling it, she'll put babies in jars and sell them.

Of course no reasonable person would actually think that's what she means.
But Chandler, who makes jokes and plays on words a lot, pretends to think that.
So he says "You're gonna need bigger jars" because (as Fumble pointed out in a comment) you cannot fit a normal-sized baby in a normal-sized jam jar.

Comment: Jokes based on the mistreatment of babies, are, for whatever reason, pretty ancient, e.g. Q. What is the difference between a truck load of sand and a truck load of babies? A. You can't shift sand with a pitchfork. First heard by me at age 10 in 1962.